# Application of List Ranking algorithm

Tags: list

I've been reading about List Ranking Algorithm from many sources like
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~scandal/alg/listrank.html
I found that it is useful in Parallel Tree Contraction,Euler tour of tree etc.but i'm not getting actual use of this list algorithm in above applications.Does anyone have any idea of how List ranking is useful in these or any algorithms?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I can imagine is that you can easily compute the height of all nodes in a tree. It's not exactly an algorithm, but can be pretty useful in some cases.

Comment: I know it can be pretty useful but how?any example?

Comment: For example, [AVL Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_Trees), [Red-black trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) and other [Self-balancing binary search trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree).

Comment: No No...i know these trees i'm asking how list ranking is useful in calculating height of these trees?

Comment: From the first article in Wikipedia: _"The balance factor of a node is the height of its left subtree minus the height of its right subtree (sometimes opposite) and a node with balance factor 1, 0, or −1 is considered balanced. A node with any other balance factor is considered unbalanced and requires rebalancing the tree. The balance factor is either stored directly at each node or computed from the heights of the subtrees."_

You just can't balance your AVL tree without the heights...